# bypass character limit in Sed and the replacement / character?

Tags: regex, sed

I'm Using windows Xp.

I want to replace a word of length 200,000 characters and CMD has problems (the input line is too long). With Linux, does the terminal have same length problems?

If I replace many words with many other words, I can't replace a character with `/` because the CMD give an output error.

Is there a solution to bypass this problems?

Comment: you want to replace a single 200,000 character word with something else?  Are you sure you're doing this right?  Certainly an atypical usage.  Can we get an example?  (NOT the whole 200k thing... be nice!)

Comment: I agree with @lornix, we probably need an example--maybe a toy example that shows the basic problem. I've successfully used `sed` on *NIX for text replacement in 141MB text files--inside a script. If you want help with `sed`, you'll definitely need to show us more.

Comment: Also, *note*, if you're looking to search or replace `/` with `sed`, you ought to use something else for an expression delimiter.  Ex. Use `s%search-pattern%replacement%` instead of `s/search-pattern/replacement/`.  Use a delimiter that is not in any of your expressions.

Comment: There is no *obligation* whatsoever to use a replacement character for `/`. You only need to escape each `/` in your search-pattern to `\/`. The feature is only a convenience when you *know* what your search pattern contains. However, if you have a dynamic/unknown search pattern, then you need to be aware of all characters which can end up in that *search-pattern*, and choose a character which won't occur as the delimiter, or escape each `/` to `\/`... btw: The delimiter is only significant in relation to the *search-pattern*. The data being searched can in no way clash with the delimiter.

Comment: thanks guys. Change delimiter is working, i'm using £ delimiter. 200k is very big word..no, I wanted to see if CMD was unable to bear the load of work .. but I could perhaps create a batch file to automate the replacement tasks for big word in CMD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your question about the Linux terminal command line. The answer is: It can handle much larger strings, which are pretty much dependant on how much free RAM you have. Eg. From the command line, I just ran `printf '%s'` with a 20,000,000 byte string; it had no problems. I also ran it through `sed.exe` (in a Linux *[wine](http://www.winehq.org/about/)* environment); this worked fine, too... Whatever the command line limit may be, it also depends on what the program you are feeding such large strings can handle as their command input maximum size.

But it is an unusual/strange situation in which you would want to pass such large strings to a program, because you will at some point reach a maximum.

With `sed` and such large strings, you can do either of two things:

1. Write your data to a file and use:

   `sed "s@ab/cd@AB_CD@" my_data_file`
2. pipe (|) the output of a command to sed's standard input:

   `my_data_app | sed "s@ab/cd@AB_CD@"`

Note that *sed* itself may have some line length limit, but from memory, GNU sed's limit is quite high.

Also, instead of the default `/`, I have used `@`, but you can use pretty much anything you like.

Comment: @user143822.  Be aware that *nix uses `UTF-8` encoding for its textfiles. Windows does not.

Comment: Yes, my text file are UTF-8 encoding, japanese, chinese characters sometimes..but I'm forced to use windows CMD to launch command in sed or can i create a .bat file or something similar?

Comment: I ran `sed.exe` in `wine` quite happily.   The "sed.exe" I used was the GNU-for Windows version 4.2... I used a `bat` file which contained:   `sed.exe -n "s@a/@-=@gp" file.in > file.out` ... also,piping to stdin works: `type file.in | sed.exe -n "s@a/@-=@gp" > file.out`

Comment: Ok..but if i want replace many words with other many words but that there are several files? What command should I use? <xxx.txt>yyy.txt  command is good only for words located in 1 file not words that are located on different files.

Comment: Re many replacements: `sed "s/one/ONE/g; s/two/TWO/g; s/etc/ETC/g" file.in >file.out` ... Re replacing in many **input** files, you can do each indivisually (of course), but to do all of them at once: `sed "s/a/b" file1 file2 file3 > file.out`  .. Is this what you mean? .. Note that you *do not need* to use `<xxx.txt`. Actually don't use it unless you have a specific reason. Just `xxx.txt` after your pattern works nicely with `sed`, which accepts input file names as parameters (one, or many filenames).

Comment: I have not really understood the command. Suppose we replace words like james, frank, matt located in this input files: one.txt, two.txt, three.txt. Suppose you use the @ as a delimiter. What is the exact command? The point is that I do not have to create a single file as output, but only modify input files

Comment: I just tried to go to chat, but you don't have enough reputation yet :( .. I've marked up your question; maybe that will be enough(?) ... I think I know what you mean now. I think you want to change a fixed set of words, ie. The same set of words are to be applied to each input file; and each input ful is to be processed seperately; an you need to do it in Windows (via a .bat file). Do I have the right idea now?

Comment: i create now this .bat sed "s/alfa/python/g;" a.txt >a1.txt 
sed "s/beta/gamma/g;" b.txt >b1.txt  In file a.txt i want replace alpha with python but i must create output file (a1). This command works..but i have long list words to modify into many files. Do you think I use Excel to create these commands?

Comment: How long is long?  and it may be easier to use a batch file to create your sed script? . I've been using  Linux exclusively for almost 2 years now, and forgotten a lot of my Windows.cmd syntax,  you can put your input files into a loop: (this syntax may be wrong): `FOR %f IN (file1 file2 file3) DO echo sed.exe -i "s/one/ONE/g; s/two/TWO/" %%f`  .. Note the `sed -i` will replace your original file. *Do not use **-i** unless you have BACKED UP your input data*. and whatever you do, TEST with test files.. UPDATE your question with more DETAIL, and someone may give better Windows info than I can.

Comment: mmm.. i I tried to create a bat FOR %f IN (a.txt b.txt) DO echo sed.exe -i "s/alfa/ONE/g; s/beta/TWO/g;" %%f    but seems doesn't work. Instead, sed.exe -i "s/alfa/python/g;" a.txt seems work change inside a.txt and create a strange file like this: sedlta7QG without extensions. I look inside this files and these are original files..is there a simply command or is that all right?? But the file to change must have an extension? Because sometimes i have txt files without extension and SED seems doesn't work..is same thing in linux?

Comment: That unusually named file is possibly the temporary file which `sed -i` uses, or it could be an auto-backup (sed in Windows may behave a little differently to sed in Linux).. the `dlta` may imply a `delta`(difference) to the original, but I would have expected it to disappear on completion.

Comment: Peter, that's fine, thank you so much support, really.

Comment: mmm..I have a problem to replace "" character using sed. I have problems with command sed -i "s/""/One..." 1.txt Is there a solution using sed? How can i use different delimiter to "? / yes, but " ?

Comment: You do not need to change the delimiter at all! (You can change it if you like, but you don't **need** to).. However, if you use `/` as your delimiter, you **must** use `\/` for each `/` in your */search/replace pattern*.  The *backslash* **escapes** the `/` so that it is treated as a **literal** `/`, regardless of the delimiter.. A similar thing happens when you put your quoting delimiter `"` into your */search/replace/ pattern*: you must *escape* it: `\"` -- eg. `sed "s/\"/x/"` -- The `""` construct is application dependant -- sed uses the *escape* `\​` construct, not `""`

Comment: btw: this site is not intended to have such long comment sessions.. When it gets beyond more than 4,5,6. it is possibly a sign that you need to ask another question (which you do at this point). A new question gives you a broader chance of getting the answer you are looking for.. Comment trails like this get lost to the general viewer.  Also there is a chat feature which I tried earlier, but you didn't have enough reputation (you do now).. but you need to ask new question/s, or at least update your original question with your new specifications (if they aren't too different).

Comment: yes..i just create another questions about sed..can u help me? http://superuser.com/questions/446089/replace-special-text-with-sed

Answer (score 1):

I am using sed for windows on win7.  I ran into a problem where the replacement string was just too large.  I was using this to replace sections of configuration files and after around 10,000 chars it would stop working and give an error of Unable to find specified file.

I ended up having to break the replace into 2 operations.  The fist would fill in 1/2 of the data and end with ###ENDOFSECTION### and then then other replace would replace the ###ENDOFSECTION### with the rest of the data.  Not sure if this is just a windows limit or not.