# Replace special text with sed?

Tags: command-line, sed

I'm using CMD on Windows Xp to replace special text with Sed. I'm using this command for replace special characters like `$ or *` :

```
sed -i "s/\*/123/g;" 1.txt
```

But how command must i use to replace this strings with `ciao!` in my text files? Is possible?

```
\\
\\\
""
sed.exe -i "s/{\*)(//123/
sed -i "s/\\/123/g;" 1.txt
```

the previous command does not work because i have `\`, `"` and other special strings that sed use to make regex.

Comment: Please give an example of a source string and the desired target string. For example: *I want to turn `*/123` into `"ciao!"`*

Comment: i want to turn  `sed -i^/\\*$/$[{" ;" 1.txt` into `Ciao!`

Comment: You want the source string to contain the actual sed *command*? `o.O`

Comment: yes, i want replace sed command with special strings into my text files.

Comment: You did not have "sed" in your question at all, you used "123". You should edit your question to replace the source string with your actual example string.

Comment: *sigh* Your source string still does not include “sed”, so it is still not clear what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking for *literal* strings with a regular expression, when the search-string contains special characters, is sometimes not as simple as looking for patterns, but you can do it with a bit of juggling.

Note: The `echo` command must cater for CMD-special-characters, so it needs `^^` to escape a single `^` and `^|` to escape `|` ... You don't need CMD's escape-character `^` if you type directly into the file.

---

*Step 1:* Create a file, named *literal-srch-strings.txt*, which containing the exact (unaltered) string to be replaced.  There are 2 ways to create this file:

1. As a command issued at CMD's *commandline*, or as a command in a .cmd/.bat *command-script*.

   `echo sed -i^^/\\*$/$[{" ;"> literal-srch-strings.txt`
2. Make  *literal-srch-strings.txt* yourself, in your text editor.
   In this case, you *should not* use the CMD-escape-character `^`, so the line is has just one `^`, not `^^` -- This is because you are bypassing the CMD-shell.
   Here is what is needed in the .txt file (just as the filename says :)

   `sed -i^/\\*$/$[{" ;"`

---

*Step 2:* Make a *sed script*, named  *str-to-regex.sed* , to convert the string(s) into sed regex(s).
Note that the same issue of the CMD-escape-character `^` applies to this step, so again, there are 2 ways you can create the .sed file:

1. As a command:

   `echo s/[]\/$*.^^^|[]/\\^&/g; s/.*/s\/^&\/Ciao!\/g/> str-to-regex.sed`
2. Using your text editor, make a file named *str-to-regex.sed*, containing:

   `s/[]\/$*.^|[]/\\&/g; s/.*/s\/&\/Ciao!\/g/`

---

*Step 3:* Run the *sed-script* which converts the string into a sed regeular expression, and
send its output to another sed-script, *replace-text.sed*, which will make the actual replacement.

```
sed -f str-to-regex.sed  literal-srch-strings.txt > replace-text.sed
```

---

*Step 4:* Run *replace-text.sed* -- For the test we can use *literal-srch-strings.txt* as the input file, but you can, of course, use any input file.

```
sed -f replace-text.sed  literal-srch-strings.txt
```

---

Here is the output:

```
Ciao!
```

Comment: very difficult..i try so also   --> echo '"{\*)(//123/$$' sed -i "s/[\"][{][\\][*][)][(][/][/]123[/][$][$]/xx/" 1.txt

Comment: It's difficult because your example is a tricky pattern. It's not that hard, once you get the feel of it, but you might find that juggling text like this would be easier in a bash shell, rather than a CMD-shell..  You might be interested to try `cygwin` (which presents you with a window similar  to CMD, but it runs `bash` which is *much* more flexible than CMD.

Comment: Peter, i try to follow your steps but i made a few mistakes, can u help me? look my video please http://nathan3000.altervista.org/Test_Vari/sedx.htm

Comment: Note that *Step 2* will cater for *any input string* (not just your example string)... However if you use any of these three characters in your *replacement string* `&`,`/`,`\​`, you must escape them as `\&`,`\/`,`\\​` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i try now but I still have problems. Using CMD command: at **echo s/[]\/$*.^^^|[]/\\&/g; s/.*/s\/^&\/Ciao!\//g> str-to-regex.sed** cmd give me error: *'/g' is not recognized as an internal or external command*. using both method(cmd and manually creating files) at **sed -f str-to-regex.sed  literal-srch-strings.txt > replace-text.sed** cmd give me this error *sed: file str-to-regex.sed line 1: unterminated 's' command*

Comment: Watch the video to better understand my steps to detect errors http://nathan3000.altervista.org/Test_Vari/sed_error2.htm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4061/discussion-between-user143822-and-peter-o)

Comment: yeah, now it works..but *Ciao!* it appears on CMD not inside text files..u can solve this issue? http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/9725/rightcommand.png Another question..but if i have many words with special characters can i create a table like this `$-->\$` , `^-->^^` , `&-->\&` etc to recall in sed..? Because replace  manually every special character is very long

Comment: My chat is still not working.. I'll try another browser.

Comment: As presented in the answer, *sed* outputs "Ciao!" to *stdout* (standard-out)... If you want to overwrite your input file, you can use sed's `-i` option (make a backup first). If you want to write to a different file, it is simply a matter of redirecting *stdout* to that file. Use `> my-output-file` to start a new output file or overwirte an existing one... or `>> my-output-file` to append to an existing  file... # And, yes a table is possible, but it entails another level of complexity.. If you only want to change literal strings there may be easier ways than *sed*. Ask another question.

Comment: i create a question about table here: http://superuser.com/questions/447178/using-a-table-or-script-in-sed-to-replace-many-special-characters-with-escape-ch  Can u help me please?

Comment: Have u idea how to make table-script?

Comment: Yes, I certainly do :) .. Although it is simple in concept, it is not quite so simple to get it rock-solid..   (I'm working on it, but getting it to work in Windows is the main problem for me... bash-shell has a very supporting framework for joining up all the segments (I spent 15, and more working with Windows CMD shell, and it ws 15 years of frustration :) ... It would be easier to do this in another scripting language, but I'll keep on with `sed`. It is interesting. Must you use CMD? Can you use [cygwin for windows](http://www.cygwin.com/) instead?

Answer (score 0):

To override the meaning of special characters on the command-line (or lines in a batch file), escape them with the ^ (carat) character. To enter a literal carat character, use two of them in a row.

Comment: what is the exactly command for replace strings like this `sed.exe -i "s/{\*)(//123/$$` ?

Comment: @user143822: I'd start with the backslash and dollar signs (assuming the quote isn't just a standalone one as shown in your comment, if it is, it too).

Comment: mmm..the command is this?  `sed.exe -i "/{^\*)(//123/^$^$` ? doesn' work though i replace delimiter with @ `sed -i "s@sed.exe -i "/{^\*)(//123/^$^$@Ciao!@g; 1.txt`

Comment: @user143822: try `^"{^\*)(//123/^$^$`. You could also try `echo`ing whatever you're attempting to use to get an idea of what is being missed.

Comment: @user143822: You might also need to put quotes around everything you want to pass sed, like `"^"{^\*)(//123/^$^$"`.

Comment: strange..the command give me no error but nothing change. I use this command `sed -i "s£"^"{^\^*)(//123/^$^$"£xx£g;" 1.txt` to change this text `"{\*)(//123/$$`. `£` is the delimiter, `xx` is new text..but nothing change