# Using a table or script in sed to replace many special characters with escape characters?

Tags: command-line, sed

If u want replace special characters using sed you can use different ways, but the problem is you have to replace many (100+) special characters with escape characters in many files.

so it needs: (thanks Peter)

`^^` to escape a single `^`
`^|` to escape `|` 
`\&`  to escape `&`  
`\/` to escape `/` 
`\\`​ to escape `\`

Suppose to have 100+ strings examples in many files:

```
sed.exe -i "s/{\*)(//123/
sed -i "s/\\/123/g;" 1.txt
sed.exe -i "s/{\*)(//123/
sed -i "s/\\/123/g;" 1.txt
.....
.....
```

these strings containing many special characters to escape (we have 100+ strings)..
Escaping manually is a very long work..so i need create a table script similar to [wReplace](http://www.sharktime.com/us_wReplaceScreenshots.html) to call in command prompt for escaping special characters and then replacing them with my words.
How can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `^^` for `^`, and `^|` for `|`, and `^&` for `&`... are not a requirement of `sed`. The `^` *escape-character* is required by the CMD-shell. If your text is exposed to neither the command-line nor a command parameter in a .cmd/.bat command-script, you only need to consider *sed's* escape-character which is a backslash `\​` ... They are two quite seperate scopes (which can overlap, so it is often better to keep it all withn sed's scope, as the following does.

Here is a `sed` script which will replace any number of *find-strings* you sepcify, with their complementary *replacement-string*. The general format of the strings is a cross between a `sed` substitution-command (*s/abc/xyz/p*) and a tabular format.  You can "stretch" the middle delimiter so that you can line things up.
You can use a FIXED string pattern (*F/...*), or a normal *sed-style* regular expression pattern  (*s/...*)... and you can adjust `sed -n` and each `/p`(in table.txt) as needed.

You need 3 files for a minimal run (and a 4th, dynamically derrived from table.txt):

1. the main script   *table-to-regex.sed*
2. the table file       *table.txt*
3. the target file      *file-to-chanage.txt*
4. derrived script       *table-derrived.sed*

To run one table against one target file.

```
sed -nf table-to-regex.sed  table.txt > table-derrived.sed
# Here, check `table-derrived.sed` for errors as described in the example *table.txt*.  

sed -nf table-derrived.sed  file-to-change.txt
# Redirect *sed's* output via `>` or `>>` as need be, or use `sed -i -nf`
```

If you want to run *table.txt* against many files, just put the above code snippet into a simple loop to suit your requirements.   I can do it trivially in *bash*, but someone more aware of the Windows CMD-shell would be better suited than I to set that up.

---

Here is the script: *table-to-regex.sed*

```
s/[[:space:]]*$//  # remove trailing whitespace

/^$\|^[[:space:]]*#/{p; b}  # empty and sed-style comment lines: print and branch
                            # printing keeps line numbers; for referencing errors

/^\([Fs]\)\(.\)\(.*\2\)\{4\}/{  # too many delims ERROR
      s/^/# error + # /p        # print a flagged/commented error
      b }                       # branch

/^\([Fs]\)\(.\)\(.*\2\)\{3\}/{                  # this may be a long-form 2nd delimiter
   /^\([Fs]\)\(.\)\(.*\2[[:space:]]*\2.*\2\)/{  # is long-form 2nd delimiter OK?
      s/^\([Fs]\)\(.\)\(.*\)\2[[:space:]]*\2\(.*\)\2\(.*\)/\1\2\n\3\n\4\n\5/
      t OK                                      # branch on true to :OK
   }; s/^/# error L # /p                        # print a flagged/commented error
      b }                                       # branch: long-form 2nd delimiter ERROR

/^\([Fs]\)\(.\)\(.*\2\)\{2\}/{     # this may be short-form delimiters
   /^\([Fs]\)\(.\)\(.*\2.*\2\)/{   # is short-form delimiters OK?
      s/^\([Fs]\)\(.\)\(.*\)\2\(.*\)\2\(.*\)/\1\2\n\3\n\4\n\5/
      t OK                         # branch on true to :OK  
   }; s/^/# error S # /p           # print a flagged/commented error
      b }                          # branch: short-form delimiters ERROR

{ s/^/# error - # /p        # print a flagged/commented error
  b }                       # branch: too few delimiters ERROR

:OK     # delimiters are okay
#============================
h   # copy the pattern-space to the hold space

# NOTE: /^s/ lines are considered to contain regex patterns, not FIXED strings.
/^s/{    s/^s\(.\)\n/s\1/   # shrink long-form delimiter to short-form
     :s; s/^s\(.\)\([^\n]*\)\n/s\1\2\1/; t s  # branch on true to :s 
      p; b }                                  # print and branch

# The following code handles FIXED-string /^F/ lines

s/^F.\n\([^\n]*\)\n.*/\1/  # isolate the literal find-string in the pattern-space
s/[]\/$*.^|[]/\\&/g        # convert the literal find-string into a regex of itself
H                          # append \n + find-regex to the hold-space

g   # Copy the modified hold-space back into the pattern-space

s/^F.\n[^\n]*\n\([^\n]*\)\n.*/\1/  # isolate the literal repl-string in the pattern-space
s/[\/&]/\\&/g                      # convert the literal repl-string into a regex of itself
H                                  # append \n + repl-regex to the hold-space

g   # Copy the modified hold-space back into the pattern-space

# Rearrange pattern-space into a / delimited command: s/find/repl/...      
s/^\(F.\)\n\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)$/s\/\5\/\6\/\4/

p   # Print the modified find-and-replace regular expression line
```

---

Here is an example table file, with a description of how it works: *table.txt*

```
# The script expects an input table file, which can contain 
#   comment, blank, and substitution lines. The text you are
#   now reading is part of an input table file.

# Comment lines begin with optional whitespace followed by #

# Each substitution line must start with: 's' or 'F'
#  's' lines are treated as a normal `sed` substitution regular expressions
#  'F' lines are considered to contain `FIXED` (literal) string expressions 
# The 's' or 'F' must be followed by the 1st of 3 delimiters   
#   which must not appear elsewhere on the same line.
# A pre-test is performed to ensure conformity. Lines with 
#   too many or too few delimiters, or no 's' or 'F', are flagged   
#   with the text '# error ? #', which effectively comments them out.
#   '?' can be: '-' too few, '+' too many, 'L' long-form, 'S' short-form
#   Here is an example of a long-form error, as it appears in the output. 

# error L # s/example/(7+3)/2=5/

# 1st delimiter, eg '/' must be a single character.
# 2nd (middle) delimiter has two possible forms:
#   Either it is exactly the same as the 1st delimiter: '/' (short-form)
#   or it has a double-form for column alignment: '/      /' (long-form)
#   The long-form can have any anount of whitespace between the 2 '/'s   
# 3rd delimiter must be the same as the 1st delimiter,

# After the 3rd delimiter, you can put any of sed's 
#    substitution commands, eg. 'g'

# With one condition, a trailing '#' comment to 's' and 'F' lines is
#    valid. The condition is that no delimiter character can be in the 
#    comment (delimiters must not appear elsewhere on the same line)

# For 's' type lines, it is implied that *you* have included all the 
#    necessary sed-escape characters!  The script does not add any 
#    sed-escape characters for 's' type lines. It will, however, 
#    convert a long-form middle-delimiter into a short-form delimiter.   

# For 'F' type lines, it is implied that both strings (find and replace) 
#    are FIXED/literal-strings. The script does add the  necessary 
#    sed-escape characters for 'F' type lines. It will also 
#    convert a long-form middle-delimiter into a short-form delimiter.   

# The result is a sed-script which contains one sed-substitution 
#    statement per line; it is just a modified version of your 
#    's' and 'F' strings "table" file.

# Note that the 1st delimiter is *always* in column 2.

# Here are some sample 's' and 'F' lines, with comments:
#

F/abc/ABC/gp               #-> These 3 are the same for 's' and 'F', 
s/abc/ABC/gp               #-> as no characters need to be escaped,  
s/abc/         /ABC/gp     #-> and the 2nd delimiter shrinks to one  

F/^F=Fixed/    /\1okay/p   # \1 is okay here, It is a FIXED literal
s|^s=sed regex||\1FAIL|p   # \1 will FAIL: back-reference not defined!

F|\\\\|////|               # this line == next line 
F|\\\\|        |////|p     # this line == previous line  
s|\\\\|        |////|p     # this line is different; 's' vs 'F'

F_Hello! ^.&`//\\*$/['{'$";"`_    _Ciao!_   # literal find / replace
```

---

Here is a sample input file whose text you wish to change: *file-to-chanage.txt*

```
abc abc
^F=Fixed
   s=sed regex
\\\\ \\\\ \\\\ \\\\
Hello! ^.&`//\\*$/['{'$";"`
some non-matching text
```

Comment: i'm trying to understand..i copy your texts and i paste them in 3 files: **table-to-regex.sed**, **table.txt**, **table-derrived.sed**. But when i try to run the 2nd command *sed -nf table-derrived.sed  file-to-chanage.txt* the CMD gives me this error: http://img152.imageshack.us/img152/30/76715330.png I hope I did the right thing by copying the text literally in 3 files

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is supposed to happen... That particular line is there to intentionally create an error; to show you what *not* to do.. Read the line's comment. All the lines in **table.txt** have comments describing what they do... Here is line 58 in **table.txt**: `s|^s=sed regex||\1FAIL|   # \1 will FAIL: back-reference not defined!` . That line has the `||` changed to `|` in **table-derrived.sed** to become: `s|^s=sed regex|\1FAIL|   # \1 will FAIL: back-reference not defined!`

Comment: continued... That particular line is an `s` type, not an `F` type, so as stated in the main script **table-to-regex.sed**: `# NOTE: /^s/ lines are considered to contain regex patterns, not FIXED strings.` ... If you provide a bad regeular expression, it will FAIL. The error is caused because sed sees `\1` in a *backreference*, but no such back reference was defined in the search pattern. There is no way of trapping that error, short of writing a full regular expression parser. That type of error shouldn't happen with type `F` lines, because they are treated as FIXED (not regular expressions)

Comment: mmm..yes, i believe to understand now the difference from **s** and **F** lines. But i don't understand well how can i do exactly to replace using your text/table files. The commands `sed -nf table-to-regex.sed  table.txt > table-derrived.sed` and `sed -nf table-derrived.sed  file-to-chanage.txt` are valid? i don't understand if i can't insert in my text files strings like this *sed -i "s/\\/123/g;" 1.txt*?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean.. If you want to change a literal string *"HELLO"* to *"Hello"*, then you can put this line into *table.txt*: `F/HELLO/Hello/p`...  That is the only preparation you need to do... Then run the 2 commands shown in the answer... If "HELLO" is of unknown case, like "hello" or "HeLLo", then you can use a regular expression substitution command, like: `s/hello/Hello/ip`...  The `i` means consider the search pattern ("hello") as case insensitive... Note, that the only time you really need `F` is when the LITERAL search string contains any of these: `]\/$*.^|[`

Comment: yes, i want change literal strings contains **]\/$..**. I don't care about the *case* of words in this moment just replace literal strings  with other words. But the problem is that i have 100+ literal strings located on several files. How can i prepare these strings for sed? Obviously I know the strings to replace

Comment: 100+ strings. Do you currently have them in a list somewhere?. To make **table.txt**, you need a list of the strings *and* their replacements. You can't make **table.txt** until you know what is going into it... 
From that list, you just prepare 100+ lines like *`F:a]b\c/$*.^d|e[f:       :hello:p` ... then, to change 100+ files, you need to run a loop (as mentioned in the answer).. Only you know which strings to process; Just use your text editor. It is only 100+ lines of `F:  :  :p` or `F:  :       :  :p` if you prefer. It sholdn't take long (I think you use Notepad++.. .it will be easy).

Comment: mmm..in your example above *F_Hello! ^.&//\\*$/['{'$";"_    _Ciao!_   # literal find / replace`* the string to replace with *Ciao!* is `^.&``//\\*$/['{'$";"`? Can i just paste my literally list strings inside table.txt? Can u take a screenshot to clarify, please? Why do u say prepare the lines like `F:a]b\c/$*.^d|e[f: :hello:p`? not just copy them literally as they are?

Comment: They **are** both literal... `a]b\c/$*.^d|e[f` and `Hello! ^.&``//\\*$/['{'$";"` are the **LITERAL** strings to be replaced... just as in your previous question... `Hello! ^.&``//\\*$/['{'$";"` is just an example of a literal string which contains characters which must be handled specially by sed. I can't see the point of a screen-shot, because all you will see is **exactly** what you have put into you last comment, and as I have put into my comments, and answer. `F` means that any and every string after `F` is treated as a **LITERAL** string...   `:` and `_` are just any suitable delimiter

Comment: *Can I just paste my list of literal strings inside table.txt?* The answer is **YES**, but only when you use the **F** prefix command with an appropriate delimiter; `/` for almost all cases. The only time you must use a different delimiter is when that same character appears anywhere else on that line. In *table.txt* your lines should look like this: `F/my-literal-string/MY-REPLACEMENT/p` .. it is very simple; you must not change your literal text in any way. you must not change your replacement text in any way; but you must use a delimiter which does not appear elsewhere on that line.

Comment: ok..now i understand the table-derrived. OK, i just paste in this form `F/$[]$/"$/p` in *table.txt*. I run your command on CMD: `sed -nf table-to-regex.sed  table.txt > table-derrived.sed `. new file is created. I look inside *table-derrived* and i have `F/$[]$/"$/p` converted so: `s/\$\[\]\$/"$/p`. **"$** is my replacement. I try to run 2nd command in 3 ways but i have errors: http://img338.imageshack.us/img338/4034/errorsed.png Strange because the content of table-derrived seems to be valid, look here: http://pastebin.com/F41LQs7R In *file-to-change* i added the text to replace, `$[]$`

Comment: You are using the `-i` option without the `-nf`, **and** you are also trying to write to a file called `1.txt`... While you are testing this, don't change any of the options. Try it exactly as you see those 2 commands in the answer (except for my typing mistake of **chanage"* )... And when you use `-i`, you shouldn't be trying to redirect it to another file... I have tested it again, on XP in a VM, with your data, and it works fine. ( I find it "strange" that you find it "strange" that it looked right :) but I know what you mean; I've been the many times, myself.

Comment: Finally i solve the problem..but i had to delete a portion of text from *table.txt* because **s|^s=sed regex||\1FAIL|p** was troubling me..errors were caused because I did not think that I should delete that text, foolishly thought that sed not consider it as string..That's working now the command..yes..but for a single file located in the same folder of sed..but i have problems if have to replace text files located on different folder..what is the command to replace on *different* or a *range* folders? **sed -i -nf table-derrived.sed  C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\2.txt** doesn't working

Comment: mmm..another problem..in my **file-to-change.txt** i have 3 strings: *alfa*, *beta*, *gamma*. In my **table.txt** i insert *F/alfa/"$/p* and *F/gamma/Ciao!/p* because i want change only **alfa** and **gamma** strings NOT other strings. When i run `sed -i -nf table-derrived.sed  file-to-change.txt` the strings *beta* inside *file-to-change.txt* **no longer exists**! there are my replacements but not other strings!

Comment: You should be **very** careful about how you use the `-i` option. You can very easily lose a lot of your data if you don't understand exactly what all the switches mean. I have used `-n` on the command-line, and `/p` inside *table.txt*, but this is probably not what you will need! With those settings it only prints lines in which a replacement is made; all others are lost!... You should read the sed manual, or at least run `sed --help |more`... Re. your error: You need to put quotes around filenames which contain spaces: `"C:\Program Files\GnuWin32\2.txt"`.. consider using `cygwin` its better.

Comment: yes..with quotes it works. Peter, i try this command `sed -i -f table-derrived.sed  file-to-change.txt`..in this case the string *beta* is not canceled but *alfa*,*gamma* are replaced twice..is normally?

Comment: StackExchange sites have special chat facilities for extenced discussions like this. Unfortunately I can't get mine to work, but if you wish to discuss this further, and you have an IRC client ( `mIRC` is the most common one for Windows), then we can chat at  `irc.freenode.com` (you can just type `/connect irc.freenode.com` on mIRC's command-line,  and then when the connection is established, type this command: `/join #su447178` .. I am there now...  ci vediamo.

Comment: thank you very much..remove **p** from table.txt and the **n** from second command